# Laplace equation in eletrostatics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

That half of the $ xz$-plane for which $x$ is positive is at zero potential except for the strip between $x = 0$ and $x = a$ which is at potential $Vo$. The whole of the $yz$-plane is at zero potential. Show that the potential at any point for which $x$ and $y$ are positive is:
$$\pi V = V_0 \left( \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x-a} - 2 \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} + \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x+a}\right).$$

That is the first question of chapter 4 from Smythe's book. I tried to use the standard solutions for Laplace equation in Cartesian coordinates but it looks like it doesn't satisfy the boundary conditions in this situation.

Comment: I don't mean to be a smartass, but technically because of the uniqueness theorem, just showing that $\nabla^2V=0$ and that it satisfies the boundary conditions suffices for proving that $V$ is the correct solution. The reason it "works" is that first you choose a definition of $\tan^{-1}$ where the output is always positive, so negative values give you a $\tan^{-1}(-x)=\pi-\tan^{-1}(x)$. Then you need to use the limit as $y\rightarrow 0$ to show the boundary conditions work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this solution by separation of variables. Instead of looking for the general solution $V$, look for non null, specific solutions of the form $V=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$. Only the homogeneous boundary conditions are kept, the inhomogenous ones are only required to be non identically null. The goal is to use linearity, and hope that you can reconstruct the boundary conditions by superposing such solutions.

In your case, your problem is 2D due to the translation invariance along the $z$ axis. You want to find the potential $V(x,y)$ in the quadrant $x,y\geq 0$ satisfying the Laplace equation:
$$
\partial_x^2V+\partial_y^2V=0
$$
with the Dirichlet boundary conditions (up to a change of units, $V_0=1$ and $a=1$):
$$
V(x=0)=0\\
V(y=0,x<1)=1\quad V(y=0,x>1)=0
$$
There is actually another implicit boundary condition which will be important later:
$$
V(y\to+\infty)=0
$$

Following the recipe, you look for $V$ of the form $V(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$. Laplace’s equation becomes:
$$
X’’Y+XY’’=0
$$
and the first boundary condition becomes:
$$
X(0)Y(y)=0
$$
Since you are only interested in non trivial solutions, $Y$ is not identically null, so it becomes:
$$
X(0)=0
$$
Similarly, the third boundary condition becomes $Y(y\to+\infty)=0$. Since the goal is to match the $y=0$ boundary condition, I will fix the normalization of $Y$ such that $V(y=0)= X(x)Y(0)=X(x)$ ie $Y(0)=1$.

The separation of variables is when you rewrite Laplace’s equation:
$$
\frac{X’’}{X}=-\frac{Y’’}{Y}
$$
The RHS is $x$ independent and the $LHS$ is $y$ independent, so they are both constant, $x,y$ independent. Your problem is therefore solving two simple ODE’s which is simpler. You’d expect three kinds of solutions depending on the strict sign of the common value with $k>0$:
$$
\begin{align}
X&=\sin(kx) & Y&= \cosh(ky)+A\sinh(ky) \\
X&= x & Y&=1+Ay\\
X&= \sinh(kx) & Y&=\cos(ky)+A\sin(ky)
\end{align}
$$

The only way to match the last boundary condition is to only use first type solutions with $A=-1$. In other words:
$$
V= \sin(kx)e^{-ky}
$$

Using Fourier transform, you can reconstruct the boundary condition:
$$
\mathbb 1_{(0,1)}(x)=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{dk}{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos k}{k}\sin(kx)
$$
You therefore obtain an integral representation of your solution:
$$
V(x,y)= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{dk}{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos k}{k}\sin(kx) e^{-ky}
$$

In this special case, the boundary conditions are sufficiently simple that you can relate this integral to standard functions (this is not always the case).

Btw, it is perhaps easier if you are new to this method to consider a simpler problem.  Instead of having as a domain an entire quadrant, restrict to a square of side $L$ and impose $V=0$ at the new sides $x=L$ and $y=L$. The boundary conditions are more explicit, and the integral becomes a discrete sum, which is easier to check numerically. Sending $L\to \infty$ allows you to recover the original problem.

Indeed, the variable separated solutions are now:
$$
V(x,y) =\sin(k_nx)\frac{\sinh(k_n(L-y))}{\sinh(k_n L)}
$$
with $k_n=\frac{\pi n}{L}$ and $n\in\mathbb N^*$. As $L\to \infty$, at fixed value of $k_n$ (to $n\to\infty$ to compensate) these solutions become the previous ones. Furthermore, the $k_n$’s sample more finely the positive numbers, with an increment of $dk=\frac{\pi}{L}$, so you recover the continuum spectrum $\mathbb R_+^*$. At the same time, the reconstructed solution built from the series:
$$
V(x,y)= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2}{L} \frac{1-\cos k_n}{k_n}\sin(k_nx) \frac{\sinh(k_n(L-y))}{\sinh(k_n L)}
$$
becomes the previous integral in the $L\to\infty$ limit by using the two previous remarks (heuristically, $\frac{dk}{\pi/2}\sim\frac{2}{L}$). O think that it is even possible to calculate the series in closed form by recognizing appropriate power series (logarithm), so you could even check that the two formulas match in the large size limits.

The method is explained in many classic textbooks like Griffith’s *Introduction to Electrodynamics* (Sec. 3.3, 4th edition) or Jackson’s *Classical Electrodynamics* (Sec. 2.10).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The problem that i am struggling with is that, on my understanding, one of the boundary conditions is that the potential goes to 0 when x goes to infinity, so i don't know how a trigonometry function could satisfy that and on the case to simplify the question and make L goes to infinity, i think that would be the original problem, but with "a" going to infinity too.

Comment: Actually, you don’t have the condition that $V(x\to+\infty)=0$. It “disappears” in the large $L$ limit. You must not send $a$ to infinity too. I’ll add details of the limit in the answer.